# Logj4 is not loaded if application is deployed as a war archive

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, log4j, war

I have a Tomcat 6 server with a lot of web application directories and I have set up Log4J. It works for all application directories which are *not* deployed via a war file.

The current configuration looks like this:

**/tomcat/lib/log4j.properties**

```
# Define all the appenders
log4j.appender.root=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender 
log4j.appender.root.File=${catalina.base}/logs/tomcat.log
log4j.appender.root.Append=true
log4j.appender.root.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.root.MaxBackupIndex=5
log4j.appender.root.Encoding=UTF-8
log4j.appender.root.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.root.layout.ConversionPattern = %d [%t] %-5p %c- %m%n

# Configure which loggers log to which appenders
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, root
```

And in every single web application:

**/content/pages/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties**

```
log4j.appender.root=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.root.File=${catalina.base}/logs/pages/root.log
log4j.appender.root.Append=true
log4j.appender.root.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.root.MaxBackupIndex=5
log4j.appender.root.Encoding=UTF-8
log4j.appender.root.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.root.layout.ConversionPattern=%-5p %d (%c)%m%n

log4j.appender.pages=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.pages.File=${catalina.base}/logs/pages/pages.log
log4j.appender.pages.Append=true
log4j.appender.pages.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.pages.MaxBackupIndex=5
log4j.appender.pages.Encoding=UTF-8
log4j.appender.pages.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.pages.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c- %m%n

log4j.rootLogger=WARN, root
log4j.logger.org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[content].[/pages]=WARN, pages
```

Now the one that doesn't work: I have a file "homepageDev.war" inside my /content directory, that gets deployed every time I restart my Tomcat server, or if I trigger it manually.

**/content/homepageDev/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties**

```
log4j.appender.root=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender 
log4j.appender.root.File=${catalina.base}/logs/homepage_dev/root.log
log4j.appender.root.Append=true
log4j.appender.root.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.root.MaxBackupIndex=5
log4j.appender.root.Encoding=UTF-8
log4j.appender.root.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.root.layout.ConversionPattern = %d [%t] %-5p %c- %m%n

log4j.appender.homepage=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.homepage.File=${catalina.base}/logs/homepage_dev/homepage_dev.log
log4j.appender.homepage.Append=true
log4j.appender.homepage.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.homepage.MaxBackupIndex=5
log4j.appender.homepage.Encoding=UTF-8
log4j.appender.homepage.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.homepage.layout.ConversionPattern=%-5p %d (%c)%m%n

log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, root
log4j.logger.com.mycompany.web.homepage=DEBUG, homepage
```

I have already set up Tomcat to start with Log4J in debug mode and I get a lot of debug information for the all the other applications (e.g. /pages). But in case of the homepageDev.war application I don't get anything.

The only thing that is in the logs is:

```
[/manager]- Manager: deploy: Deploying web application at '/homepageDev'
[/manager]- Manager: Uploading WAR file to /content/homepageDev.war
Deploying web application archive homepageDev.war
```

Inside my application I'm using Log4J as the following: I have servlets with a:

```
private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(DatabaseJsonServlet.class);
```

and in the init method I call:

```
logger.debug();
```

Comment: Where is `log4j-[version].jar` located?

Comment: It is located at `/tomcat/lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar` and I have already tried to add `log4j-1.2.16.jar` inside the `/content/homepageDev/WEB-INF/lib/` directory

Answer (score 0):

Log4j will only initialize itself once, using the thread's current class loader to load `log4j.properties`. So if app A loads first, then log4j will read app A's `log4j.properties` file *and then never read another `log4j.properties` file ever again*.

If you want to be able to use log4j separately in each application, then you need to put `log4j-1.2.16.jar` in `WEB-INF/lib` for each web application.

Comment: But I have already tried that as you can read in my comment above.
And it also works for every other application that is loaded.
It only doesn't work for the deployed war archives.

Comment: Does the path exist where you are trying to put your logs? `logs/homepage_dev/`? At this point, I might hook-up a debugger and set a breakpoint in your `init()` method in your servlet.