# log4j.properties loading in tomcat

Tags: tomcat, log4j

I have multiple applications (WAR files) in one tomcat instance. However, in fact, the first classpath path found is **tomcatroot/lib**. Then all applications load the same **log4j.properties**. I'm interested in separate log4j.properties per application. What is the good practice to solve that?
In general, I suspect that since it's the same jvm, all references for log4j like

```
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

class MyClass{
   private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(MyClass.class); 

   void f() {
      log.debug("message");
   }
}
```

will take the same one configuration

Comment: Why is there a log4j.properties in tomcatroot/lib? Is that part of Tomcat or did you put it there? Usually, each application would have their own logging configuration in WEB-INF/classes.

Comment: WEB-INF/classes is deployable. But each specific log4j.properties can include also data specific for concrete installation like address of Syslog server serving that specific installation

Comment: That is a good point. However, the default log4j configuration mechanism relies on loading from classpath and if you put log4j.properties into tomcatroot/lib all applications will see it. You could try to configure an alternate filename for each app (log4j-app1.properties) to keep them apart.

Comment: I share your pain about "concrete installation". I agree that there should be externalized configuration. There does not seem to be a good and standard way. Things like JNDI are supposed to address that (but are not integrated with log4j I guess). It seems you are supposed to  "bake in" things like that on deploy time.

Comment: 1) Let's say I load separate log4j.properties. Still LogFactory.getLog(MyClass.class) will take the same shared configuration stored somewhere in stomach of log4j cause it's the same tomcat, same jvm

Comment: 2) In ideal way it should be merged programmaticly: deployable one for application specific and the static one for installation specific

Comment: If you have only separate log4j.properties, then nothing will be in Tomcat's stomach. Each app gets their own log4j (log4j.jar itself should also not be in tomcat/lib), completely independent.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32759004/logj4-is-not-loaded-if-application-is-deployed-as-a-war-archive?rq=1

Comment: 10x, I'll update the you after the check

Comment: The log4J.properties file always is "per application" if you put it in the applications class path root. You are confusing "Apache Commons Logging" and Log4J.

Comment: After all, I "discovered" an issue in tomcat's WebappClassLoader. It doesn't load resources from tomcatroot\webapps\myapp\WEB-INF\lib if it's not a jar (like log4j.properties). I've just created jar within only log4j.properties in jar's root level. Then it works well-each app has own log4j configuration. Another dirty workaround...